# open left and right side panel if (window.innerWidth > 800)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to open two side panels (panel_Left and panel_Right) only *if (window.innerWidth > 800)* but always be open panel only one

```
window.onresize = function (event) {
    if (window.innerWidth > 800) {
        window.setTimeout(openPanel, 1);
    }
    if (window.innerWidth < 800) {
        window.setTimeout(closePanel, 1);
    }
};


function closePanel() {
    $("Panel_left").panel("close");
    $("#Panel_right").panel("close");
}

function openPanel() {
    $("#Panel_left").panel("open");
    $("#Panel_right").panel("open");
}


$("#Panel_left").on("panelcreate", function (event, ui) {
    if (window.innerWidth > 800) {
        openPanel();
    }
    if (window.innerWidth < 800) {
        closePanel();
    }
});
```

Knowing
I used (jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js)

Comment: can you add html here ?

Comment: Text reorder and format improved

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
window.onresize = function(event) {
    if (window.innerWidth > 800) {
        console.log("hi");
        document.getElementById("left").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("right").style.display = "block";
        // window.setTimeout(openPanel, 1);
    } else {
        document.getElementById("right").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("left").style.display = "none";
        console.log("hello");
        // window.setTimeout(closePanel, 1);
    }
};
window.onload = function() {
    if (window.innerWidth > 800) {
        console.log("hi");
        document.getElementById("left").style.display = "block";
        document.getElementById("right").style.display = "block";
        // window.setTimeout(openPanel, 1);
    } else {
        document.getElementById("right").style.display = "none";
        document.getElementById("left").style.display = "none";
        console.log("hello");
        // window.setTimeout(closePanel, 1);
    }
}
```

```css
#left,
#right {
    width: 10%;
    display: inline-block;
}

#left {
    float: left;
}

#right {
    float: right;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <title>stack</title>
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="left">hi</div>
    <div id="right">hello</div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="controller.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

do you need this?@mo bi

Comment: **yes**   really
It is what I want to do  **So thanks for the help.**

Comment: you are welcome :) .can you please click the up arrow button beside my answer?